# Load object values to Polymer 3 component

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, web-component

Inside a polymer 3 component I have declared a object property:

```
 static get properties(): myInferface {
    return {
      myObject: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
        value:  {
          showMe: false,
          text: '',
          text2: ''
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

I use

```
 static get template() {
    return html`
          <template is="dom-if" if={{myObject.showMe}}>
           <p>{{myObject.text}}</p>
           <p>{{myObject.text2}}</p>
          </template>
    `;
```

I declare the component:

```
window.customElements.define('myComp', myClass);
```

Nothing will be shown as myObject.showMe default value is false.

I import the component inside another one and try to add the properties:

```
<myComp> 
    myObject= {{
    showMe: true,
    text: "aaa",
    text2: "bbb"
              }}
</myComp>
```

Does not work. I have also tried:

```
 <myComp> 
        myObject= {myObject {
        showMe: true,
        text: "aaa",
        text2: "bbb"
                  }}
    </myComp>
```

Does not work. Whats wrong?

Comment: Will be easier to find whats wrong if you recreate the problem in some online editor, as: https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.js`.

Here is a demo with your code snippets: https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer-element-example-mxjhuu?file=index.js

Btw. you should change the name of your component since [custom elements should be in kebab-case](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-custom-element-name):

`window.customElements.define('my-comp', myClass);`